# How do I access data variables between autogenerated Interrupts.c file?

Tags: c, embedded, interrupt-handling, 8051, simplicity-studio

I have recently started working with Simplicity Studio to develop a program for a 8051 based development board. Via the configurator, I enabled Interrupts, which creates a `Interrupts.c` file. This file isn't being explicitly included in the main file, yet the interrupts defined there work as they should.
Now, my concern is that I want to toggle a few flag variables from the interrupts, and use them in the main file. And since it is not explicitly included, the linker does not find the global variables of `Interrupts.c` and throws an error.

1. I tried including the file explicitly, but I get the error `L104: Multiple Function Definitions` for all ISR functions as well as global variables.
2. Tried making a function in the Interrupt file that only returns the global variables. That worked, but I cannot do that for every single variable, plus I won't be able to make changes in the main file and see it reflected in the Interrupts file.
3. Tried using extern and defining in the main file, and I'm greeted with `L127: Unresolved External Symbol` as well as `L128: Reference made to Unresolved External`

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. The common way is to write a header file that declares all needed global variables. Include this header file in both your main source and the ISR's source. Choose a implementation file to define the variables.

Answer (score 0):

In the Peripherals tab look for interrrupts. There usually is a setting "Generate Interrupt Functions". Disable this and include your own IRQ module to the sources.

Answer (score 0):

in the main file:

```
volatile uint87_t your_var=123;
```

in Interrupts.c:

```
extern volatile uint87_t your_var;
```